# SQL Server Permissions for Intellisense for an Active Directory User?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, users, role, intellisense

I have created an Active Directory Group and created it as a user, we'll call it "AD SQL", in my DB. I can successfully login in using Active Directory Authentication and read/write.

However, Intellisense is not working for any Active Directory users.

If I log in using my Active Directory Admin, "AD ADMIN", Intellisense works fine.

Can anyone tell me what permissions/roles/view/etc are needed for a user to have access to Intellisense?

My "AD SQL" user the following roles/permissions:

- db_owner
- db_datareader
- db_datawriter
- GRANT CONNECT (DATABASE)
- GRANT VIEW DEFINITION (DATABASE)

And I have already tried Refreshing Cache/Restarting SSMS.

Comment: After you grant db_owner to use, you don't need to grant rest of the permissions you mentioned.

Comment: Make sure you didn't DENY something from AD SQL. From my experience, intellisense should work "with the basics". I just tried that with only db_datareader and it worked fine. My guess is that DENY of something essential was done either directly to AD USER or to some other windows login for a windows group that the person is a member of.

Comment: And make sure that intellisense is [enabled](https://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/How-to-Enable-and-Refresh-IntelliSense-in-SQL-Server-Management-Studio/). Refreshing intellisense will not automatically enable it if it is disabled.

Comment: Have you installed any third party add-ins for SSMS like Apex and Redgate? Sometime it causes problems. I faced similar issue which fixed post installation of the add-ins.